# System of equations: $3^x + 4^x + 5^x = 2^x \cdot 3^{x -1} \cdot y$

Tags: contest-math, systems-of-equations, exponentiation

This was taken from a local mathematical olympiad in Romania. It is from the year 2003.
Solve for $x, y, z \in \mathbb{R}$:
$$
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
3^x + 4^x + 5^x = 2^x \cdot 3^{x -1} \cdot y \\ 
3^y + 4^y + 5^y = 2^y \cdot 3^{y -1} \cdot z \\ 
3^z + 4^z + 5^z = 2^z \cdot 3^{z -1} \cdot x
\end{array}
\right. 
$$
So, the first thing I notice was $4^x = 2^{2x} = a$ so we get a system of quadratic equations. This proved to be quite hard to deal with, so I gave it up. I also tried dividing by $2^x \cdot 3^{x - 1} \cdot y$ and the others, but it was weird to deal with. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @DietrichBurde It's still not that nice of a system, since there are $x,y,z$ terms raw in the equations as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that your system is equivalent to $$\begin{cases}f(x)=y\\ f(y)=z\\f(z)=x\end{cases}$$ Where $$f(x):=3\cdot \left[\left(\frac{3}{6}\right)^x+\left(\frac{4}{6}\right)^x+\left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^x\right]$$ Let $g(x)=f(x)-x$. Adding up the three equations yields $\sum g(x)=0$, so at least one of $g(x), g(y), g(z)$ has to be $\leqslant 0$. It's easy to see that $g(x)$ is strictly decreasing and has its only root at $x=3$.

*Case 1.* $g(x)\leqslant 0\iff x\geqslant 3$. Since $f(x)$ is also strictly decreasing, this implies that $y=f(x)\leqslant f(3)=3$. Thus $y\leqslant 3\implies z=f(y)\geqslant f(3)=3$. Hence, $z\geqslant 3\implies x=f(z)\leqslant f(3)=3$. So $x\leqslant 3$. But this is absurd unless $x=y=z=3$.

Cases 2 and 3 are analogous.

Answer (score 1):

We have:

$$\left( \frac{3}{6} \right)^x+\left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^x+\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^x =\frac{y}{3} \tag{1}$$
$$\left( \frac{3}{6} \right)^y+\left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^y+\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^y =\frac{z}{3}\tag{2}$$
$$\left( \frac{3}{6} \right)^z+\left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^z+\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^z =\frac{x}{3}\tag{3}$$
Let's denote $f(t) =\left( \frac{3}{6} \right)^t+\left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^t+\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^t  $, this function is decreasing in $t$ (you can prove it easily).
WLOG, suppose $x=\min{\{x,y,z\}}$. This implies that $x \le y$.

From (1) and (3), we have: $x \le y \implies f(x) \ge f(z) \implies x \le z$.

From (2) and (3), we have: $ x \le z \implies  f(z) \le f(y) \implies z \ge y$.

From (1) and (2), we have: $ y \le z \implies  f(x) \le f(y) \implies x \ge y$.

But we already suppose $x=\min{\{x,y,z\}}$ , hence, $x=y$. And from (1) and (2), we have $f(x) = f(y) \implies y = z$. So, $x=y=z$.

It suffices now to solve the equation
$$f(x)=\left( \frac{3}{6} \right)^x+\left( \frac{4}{6} \right)^x+\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^x =\frac{x}{3}$$
We notice that $f(x)$ is decreasing function while $=\frac{x}{3}$ is an increasing function. Thus, there is at most 1 solution. And because $x=3$ is the solution, then $x=y=z=3$ is the unique solution of the system equation.

Answer (score 1):

This is mostly a variant of NN2's answer, deriving the unique solution from an argument about the *middle* of the three variables rather than the *minimum*. I'm posting it mainly because it occurs to me that proving that each variable must be "between" the other two might be easier to follow than eyeballing the directions that a bunch of inequalities point.

Let

$$f(u)=3\left(\left(1\over2\right)^u+\left(2\over3\right)^u+\left(5\over6\right)^u\right)$$

and rewrite the system as

$$\begin{align}
f(x)&=y\\
f(y)&=z\\
f(z)&=x
\end{align}$$

Now since $1\over2$, $2\over3$, and $5\over6$ are all less than $1$, $f$ is a decreasing function of $u$. Hence if $x$ is between $y$ and $z$ (i.e., greater than or equal to one and less than or equal to the other), then $f(x)=y$ is between $f(y)=z$ and $f(z)=x$, which in turn implies $f(y)=z$ is between $f(z)=x$ and $f(x)=y$ (which in turn implies $f(z)=x$ is between $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=z$). Since at least one variable is between the other two, we conclude that each is between the others, i.e., $x=y=z$.

Finally, since $f$ is decreasing, the equation $f(u)=u$ can have at most one solution. By inspection, we see that the unique solution is $u=3$. So the OP's system of equations has $(x,y,z)=(3,3,3)$ as its unique solution.